# Why do we need ComponentStory, ComponentMeta in storybook/react

Tags: reactjs, storybook

```
import React from 'react';
import { ComponentStory, ComponentMeta } from '@storybook/react';

import Button, { Props } from 'components/Button';

export default {
  title: 'UI/Button',
  component: Button,
  argTypes: {},
} as ComponentMeta<typeof Button>;

const Template: ComponentStory<typeof Button> = ({
  onClick,
  children,
}: Props) => <Button onClick={onClick}>{children}</Button>;

export const Primary = Template.bind({});

Primary.args = {
  children: 'Button',
};
```

I don't really understand what `ComponentMeta<typeof Button>` really add , and also `ComponentStory<typeof Button>` , when you don't add it `typescript` just highlight that `.args` doesn't exist on `Template` . And also , `typeof Button` it just a `function` . Can it be written better or easier , or can I skip it, it looks strange , like boilerplate ?

Answer (score 5):

These types not only give you type safety and autocompletion for Meta and Story attributes, but they also automatically infer the props of components passed into the generics and reflect those types in the args property.

This is great because this way you don't need to export the type of props of your component just to satisfy Storybook.

Note the difference between type casting and no type casting when using Intellisense (auto-completion):
[image: type casting]

[image: no type casting]